# Unable to run JetBrains plugin at all during development

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm working on creating a JetBrains plugin, and this is driving me completely nuts right now. I had both an app and project component running and working (just starting to play around with them), but now it appears that the initComponent methods of both are not getting called when I run the plugin. I have no idea what I changed (this is just a tiny dummy/test project that I haven't put in source control yet). I'm sure it must be something really obvious, but I'm totally stumped. In theory I should be able to debug things, but I can't even get the initComponent methods to fire, so I don't know where I would set an initial breakpoint. Any ideas?

PS: The plugin devkit plugin is enabled on both my development instance of IntelliJ as well as the test instance that launches when I run my plugin project.

**Update:** I now see by looking at the idea.log when I run my plugin that the plugin I am developing is disabled for some reason:

```
2013-07-07 11:17:23,004 [   2414]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Disabled plugins: Plugin display name here (1.0), Sample (1.0)
```

As I said above, it must not have been disabled before because it was running before, however I don't see how to enable/disable the plugin that is in development (you would thing the plugin run configuration provided by IntelliJ would ensure that it is enabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I can't believe I missed this, but the plugin(s) I was developing were disabled in the preferences panel of the test instance of IntelliJ. I was able to enable the plugins in the preferences and it started working again (and they continue to work because I assume those settings are persisted either in the test project or the development sandbox settings).

I still have no idea how I disabled them in the first place, and I can't believe I didn't see that they were disabled in the preferences pane...

Comment: Remember that your plugins run in a sandbox when you launch them from a "Plugin" Run/Debug configuration, and you can always nuke out the sandbox and start over.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been another useful thing to try during troubleshooting. I now see how it got disabled in the first place. One of my components failed to initialize, so the test IntelliJ instance disabled it, and that disabled setting was persisted in my sandbox settings (because I didn't wipe them out after like you mentioned).